# what do you call this round button?

Tags: shortcut

[image]

and how can I summon that button?(hot key and other way that could summon it with mouse.)

Comment: Try the tab key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s the official PIE menu addon. Go to user preferences >> Addons >> Type in the seachbox: pie. Select all 3. Now you have special shortcut keys that will display what you see on the screencap. Specifically invoke it with tab.

Comment: thank you berry mouch!

Comment: Please mark my answer using the check icon on the left side of my answer. Thanks! Glad to help.